# Replacing a split tread on an old staircase

Tags: flooring, stairs

We have an old staircase (1900s) and after removing the carpet, before we get the new one fitted, we noticed that one of the corner steps has a lengthways split right down the middle:

[image: Photo of crack in stairs]

How easy would it be replace the step? Or alternatively would it be possible to toughen it up? One person suggested to use a thin piece of hardboard on top of it to spread the load.

I have booked out a joiner for tomorrow morning but now wondering whether I should just leave the step alone. I haven't used the joiner before so don't want him to just crash & burn to make some money so would really appreciate some advice. When I walk on the step it gives less than 1cm. There is no access to the stairs underneath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tread is loose enough to close the gap by tapping it with a hammer you may be able to glue it .If it is loose take two 3/4x3/4 inch boards that are as long as the crack.Drill four holes thru both boards big enough for a 10-24 screw.With some dry wall screws attach the boards to the tread on both sides of the crack.Apply some gorilla glue to the gap. Using the 10-24 screws draw the gap closed, allow the glue to dry, remove the 3/4" boards.Sand any glue squeezed out.

Comment: thanks. in the end we glued the gap and then attached a piece of hardboard on top. seems to have worked well. new carpet now installed and feels great!